# Need help with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with following problem: Let f be an entire function, If $Im(f)>|z|$ for all $|z|>2$, show that f is constant. I think I have to use Liouville's theorem to do this problem. That is I have to prove that f is bounded. Could you please help me how to prove that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z) = e^{if(z)}$. Then for $|z| > 2$, $|g(z)| = e^{-\text{Im}(f(z))} < e^{-|z|} < e^{-2}$. Since $g$ is continuous on the closed disc $|z| \le 2$, it is bounded by some number $M$ on this disc. Let $K = \max\{e^{-2}, M\}$. Then $|g(z)| \le K$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. Now apply Liouville's theorem to $g$ to show that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that image of entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ is actually easy to prove only by using Liouville's theorem. Look at my comment here [let $f$ be analytic and bounded above, can I prove f is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034261/let-f-be-analytic-and-bounded-above-can-i-prove-f-is-constant) .

This answers all such questions.