# let $f$ be analytic and bounded above, can I prove f is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've read up on Lioville's theorem and I was wondering if this could also be proved using the theorem:

let $f$ be analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and let $K>0$ be s.t. $|f| \geq K$, could I prove using Liouville's theorem that $f$ is constant?

I tried by defining $q(z) = 1/f(z)$ and then $|q(z)| \leq 1/K$ but we don't know if $q$ is enitre

Comment: we do now q is entire - f has no zeroes since its absolute value is bounded :D

Comment: @Assaultous2 oh silly me, thanks!

Comment: nice thought process though - i never though of "flipping" Louivilles theorem

Comment: so even though there are nonconstant analytic functions without zeroes ( for example, exponential function) , they must tend arbitrarily close to zero ( when the real part of s tends to -infinity in the case of the exponential) :D

Comment: how did you conclude that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do know that $ q(z)$ is entire since $f(z)$ has no zeroes since its absolute value is bounded from below. Hence your proposed proof works. I like your idea of flipping the essence of Louiville's Theorem. It explains why while there are nonconstant analytic functions with no zeroes ( for example $e^z$), they all have the property that their value can get arbitrarily close to zero ( in the case of $e^z$ for $Re(z) \to - \infty $).

Comment: This is actually quite nice. It proves that image of a non-constant entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $t \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $|f(z) - t| > \delta$ is impossible.